# Should we rename [obs] → [open-broadcaster-software]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-rename-request

Should [obs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obs) be renamed to [open-broadcaster-software](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-broadcaster-software)? Spelled-out names are generally clearer than abbreviations, and I accidentally created a duplicate tag at the full name when doing some cleanup of old mistagged questions.

Comment: I'm somewhat inclined to keep the main tag [tag:obs] and make a synonym for the full name.  I think it is widely more known as simply just OBS.  Even their [own website](https://obsproject.com/) puts OBS first and they refer to it primarily as so.

Comment: Then again, a synonym would just simply be remapped.  So... I'm crossed.  Maybe reword this question to be "should we rename the obs tag?" and see what the community thinks.

Comment: All meta questions implicitly ask for the community's opinion, so I don't think an edit is needed, but feel free to edit the post in that direction if you think it would help.

Comment: I've added the synonym [tag:open-broadcaster-software] -> [tag:obs]. If sentiment on this changes, it's trivial to reverse the synonym direction, but for now at least, the tag names are linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Keep it as OBS

I've never heard someone refer to OBS as anything other than OBS. Calling it "Open Broadcaster Software" sounds needlessly corporate. It would not surprise me if a significant amount of people didn't know OBS was an abbreviation, and would be confused if we didn't have a tag for it.

A synonym existing for people who do know the difference is fine, but [obs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obs) should take priority over [open-broadcaster-software](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-broadcaster-software).

Comment: I definitely always thought the “S” stood for **Suite**. 

So, +1 for keeping the more commonly used and commonly understood **OBS** as the tag, even if the full and proper name should be set as a synonym.